# Why is an OpenSSL::PKey::RSA key both private and public?

Tags: ruby, openssl, cryptography, rsa

I'm learning about the [`OpenSSL`](https://ruby.github.io/openssl/OpenSSL.html) ruby module.

Shown below is a pry session where I generate a key using the [RSA](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(algorithm)) asymmetric public key algorithm. I also call the `#private?` and `#public?` instance methods:

```
[1] pry(main)> require 'openssl'
=> true
[2] pry(main)> alices_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new 2048
=> #<OpenSSL::PKey::RSA:0x007fc0751cb028>
[3] pry(main)> alices_key.public?
=> true
[4] pry(main)> alices_key.private?
=> true
```

- Why is the `#<OpenSSL::PKey::RSA:0x007fc0751cb028>` object both public and private?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually the data structure of the private key also contains the public exponent. They are generated in the same key *pair* generation in the first place.

It is easy to store them together as the public key is the modulus + the public exponent (usually the value 0x10001, the fourth prime of Fermat). The modulus of course is also part of the private key, so that doesn't need to be duplicated.

The public key may also be used to protect against some side channel attacks although that's not such a big issue in software.

---

It depends on the software if the private key can also be used as a public key and if the public exponent is stored with the private key. But it is quite common, e.g. a private key object in PKCS#11 (used for software, smart cards and HSM's) also contains the public exponent. On the other hand Java has separate `PrivateKey` and `PublicKey` classes where the `PrivateKey` doesn't contain the public exponent (or it doesn't expose it through the public API anyway).

In the end we cannot answer the question without consulting the original OpenSSL guys (Mr. Young and Mr Hudson, I suppose) but there are good reasons for storing the public exponent as well, and as the public key is public it doesn't hurt either.